# Navbar hides top of my UITableViewController - ideas?

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uitableview, uistoryboard

So I have embedded a UITableViewController in a UINavigationController, all done in the Storyboard visual editor. Unfortunately, when my app runs, the table view extends underneath the nav bar, which looks bad and hides the pull-to-refresh control.

Any ideas how to fix this?[image: This looks like ass]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Known bug in iOS 7 beta 3 regarding UIRefreshControl :(

Answer (score 0):

Several :-)

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

or add in viewDidLoad:

```
 CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y+64,
                                  frame.size.width, frame.size.height-64);
```